# how to execute a shell command inside of a perl sub routine?

Tags: perl

How do I execute a shell command in perl if I call it through a sub routine?

For example, I can run this on the command line to get a particular value:

```
mycert-util --show test.user.myuser_cd
```

I want to run this command within a perl subroutine and call it. For example my routine would be `get_auth` and I want to print out the value of `get_auth`.

code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#&get_auth;  
#get_auth();

print "The value is: get_auth() \n";

sub get_auth
{
  $exec=`mycert-util --show test.user.myuser_cd`; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the code you show work as you want it to? If it doesn't, what is your desired behavior, and what does it do instead?

Comment: By the way, perl does not interpolate subroutine calls in double-quoted strings, so it should be `"The value is: ".get_auth()." \n"`. (And it must come after the sub definition to be recognized). But that has nothing to do with the shell command _in_ the subroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the sub, but how you call it. You cannot place sub calls inside quotes. Some equivalent alternative features below.

```
use feature qw(say);
say "The value is: ", get_auth();

sub get_auth {
   return qx(mycert-util --show test.user.myuser_cd); 
}
```

Comment: `feature` and `say` in perl 5.8?

Comment: I would assume so. Try it out.

Comment: It's probably v5.10 and forward.. no big deal, print works just as well. But why not update?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you probably need to return your $exec variable and then output it properly:

```
sub get_auth
{
  $exec=`mycert-util --show test.user.myuser_cd`; 
  return $exec;
}

print "The value is: " . get_auth() . "\n";
```